# Как произносить: "упасть нА пол или на пОл"?

Tags: фонетика

Пожалуйста, скажите мне, на какой слог падает ударение в данных случаях: одновременно, звонить, упасть нА пол или на пОл. Заранее спасибо. На запросы, в поисковике,слова "одновременно" - яндекс выделяет сразу две гласных, а на "звонить" - вообще ничего.

Comment: Мне кажется, что нужно разделять различные типы ударений. Одно дело - ударение в слове. А другое дело - сама ритмика речи и тональность. Т.е., я думаю, что в данном случае вопрос сформулирован некорректно. А яндекс и дает правильный ответ.

Answer (score 5):

В целом согласна с tmp. ЗвонИть, звонИт, звонИшь, звонЯт;
одновременно - оба варианта верны.

Можно уточнить:
Упасть куда?-нА пол(обстоятельство со  знач. дополнения), Обратить внимание, посмотреть на что? -  на пОл ( только дополнение). Ударение переходит на предлог только в обстоятельствах. Это предпочтительное ударение, в живой речи так и происходит само собой, по крайней мере, если это для транскрипции, то ударение на предлог. Если это не для учебных целей, а для простого общения, возможно сказать и "упал на пОл", т.е. ударением акцентируем внимание на пол как предмет.

Comment: >ЗвонИть, звонИт, звонИшь, звонЯт;  
  
А разве спрашивали про личные формы?! Но это ладно...

Разве в команде "лягте нА пол" (Если вы в своей квартире, // лягте на пол, три, четыре" - ВВС) "на пол" - обстоятельство?!

Comment: А Вы думаете, про инфинитив? ЗвОнить никто не скажет, человек просто "опечатался",у Вас это тоже бывает, вероятно, вопрос был про формы от "звонить", там бывают ошибки.

Comment: А что же? Лягте куда? - нА пол - обстоятельство с оттенком дополнения.

Comment: > ЗвОнить никто не скажет, человек просто "опечатался",у Вас это тоже бывает,  
  
У меня это бывает регулярно, но я не взял бы на себя смелость утверждать, что человек опечатался, когда его вполне можно понять именно так, как написано. 
Тем более есть прямое подтверждение обратного. *"а на "звонить" - вообще ничего"* - вряд ли тут тоже опечатка, да и ситуация невозмождная со "звонят - звонят", она есть везде. ладно, это не предмет спора.

Вот насчет  "нА пол - обстоятельство", пусть и "с оттенком дополнения" это уже интересно... Это по какой же грамматике сейчас детей так учат?

Comment: А, Вы хотите сказать, что вопрос "лягте - куда?". Ой, не знаю... Здесь прямое значение - "на что"... А "войти в комнату"?
Я понимаю ещё "уехать в деревню" или там "попасть в переплёт"...
Этак весь предложный падеж придется переделывать под нужды обстоятеьств...

Comment: Войти в комнату - тоже обстоятельство. Представьте, вы говорите: "Я вошел!"  Как у вас другие уточнят: во что? или куда? А вообще Людмила очень правильно отвечает о многозначности грамматического значения. Даже в учебниках, Бабайцевой, например, даются примеры для учеников с двойным подчеркиванием.

Comment: Нет, Ларf, войти в комнату - это именно "во что". Не в кухню, не в ванную... И переспосят меня скорее всего в "какую". "А куда" - если только не услвшат вообще ничего. Я так понимаю. 
Про многозначность вполне можно порассуждать, но после того, как договоримся о базовых понятиях. Иначе это начнется спор четырёх слепых о слоне.  Это я тоже так понимаю.  
Если не трудно, приведите, пожалуйста, пример фразы с существительным в предложном падеже (с предлогом А или НА), которое бы НЕ являлось обстоятельством. Если такое, конечно в принципе возможно при подобном подходе. Да, в винительном тоже.

Comment: ЗЫ. "Я повесил портрет на стенку" - "Куда повесил?" Обстоятельство? 
"Я посммотрел на висящий портрет" - "Куда посмотрел?" и проч...

Comment: Так мы долго будем спорить.Давайте посмотрим со стороны семантики отношений.Вот Валгина:Обст. места — второст.чл. предложения, служащий для выражения пространств.отношений(а) обст., выраж. место (где?),и б)направление движения (куда? откуда?).):Среди травянистой поляны стояло на сваях длинное бревенчатое помещение. Стояло где?-среди поляны на сваях. Семантич.группы дополнения:1.объектные – обознач.предмет, на который направлено действие.2- адресат,3- орудие действия,4- лицо, предмет, кот.самостоятельно выполн. действие,4. с которыми совершается действие. 
Лягте куда?-положение в пространстве.

Comment: На что? - вспомогательный вопрос, а не главный. Если обозначает место, то это обстоятельство.А вот посмотрел на что?-на портрет, на стену., на пол.Это объект глагола "посмотреть".А лечь - всё-таки куда? в какое место окруж. пространства.Как, например, завесить что?-стену.Повесить где?-на стене.Посмотрел на что? - на стену(с оттенком  куда? - в сторону стены).

Comment: tmp! Очень прошу - читайте внимательно. Я написала предложение: я вошел! Откуда здесь взяться вашему уточняющему вопросу " какую?". Вошел куда? в комнату. И уже следующий вопрос  - в какую? Вполне согласна с Людмилой. Повесил куда? на стену - обстоятельство места. Да, при изучении падежей дети задают такие вопросы, как вы. Но при изучении членов предложения их учат задавать не только падежные, но и смысловые вопросы.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем вам Яндекс как поисковик?! Смотрите в конкретных словарях, можете на том же Яндексе.

Что до конкретных слов, то дело обстоит так.

"звОнить", понятно, специально не нигде оговаривается кроме специальных словарей, тут даже иностранец ошибку вряд ли сделает.
"Одновременно" - по Лопатину оба варианта одинаково допустимы, (только не одновремЁнно); ранее правильным признавался только одноврЕменно.
"нА пол" - вот тут некая сложность. Словарный вариант - "нА пол". Но, боюсь, он единственный допустимый только в команде "нА пол!", в повелительном наклонении: "При опасности - падай на пол!" и проч.

Если же "посмотреть на пол", причем не просто себе под ноги, а именно на то, какой там под ногами паркет... Полагаю, тут скорее даже "на пОл".

Answer (score 1):

Но лучше всё-таки нА пол.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: одноврЕменно\одновремЕнно, звонИть. По поводу нА пол\на пОл.  В сочетаниях с предлогом на (с винительным падежом) в значении 
«по направлению, сверху чего-л.» ударение падает на предлог, например: упасть (сесть, лечь) нА пол. Но переноса ударения обычно не происходит, если во фразе за существительным следует поясняющее его слово или слова (подчиненные ему или связанные с ним сочинительной связью), например: на пОл деревянный.

Answer (score 0):

упасть нА пол